# How to assert param type of `gomock.Expect` call

Tags: java, unit-testing, go, gomock

I am using `gomock` for my unit test. I need to assert the type of param passed in the EXPECT setup. For example below, I need to assert the first param is any of type String, then any of type Integer, and then any of type `MyStruct`.

```
mockFoo.EXPECT().MyFunc(gomock.Any(), gomock.Any(), gomock.Any()).Return(true)
```

In Java, I'd do something like this:

```
Foo mockFoo = mock(Foo.class);
when(mockFoo.myFunc(anyString(), anyInt(), any(MyStruct.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Implements a custom [Matcher](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/mock/gomock#Matcher) for required args. For example:

```golang
type Foo interface {
    MyFunc(string) bool
}

type matcher struct {
    // implements any required fields.
}

func (n matcher) Matches(in any) bool {
    val, ok := in.(string)
    fmt.Printf("value [%v], ok [%v]\n", val, ok) // gets access to the arg
    return ok
}

func (n matcher) String() string {
    return "not match"
}
```

```
mockFoo.EXPECT().MyFunc(matcher{}).Return(true)
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/n4qLq98VSXD)</kbd>

☝ It's the simplest example.

For mote flexibility implement a custom [Matcher](https://pkg.go.dev/go.uber.org/mock/gomock#Matcher) with any required logic. Also try to use [generics](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics), for example:

```golang
type Foo interface {
    MyFunc(string, int) bool
}
```

```golang
type matcher[T any] struct {
    // implements any required fields. `matchFn` using only for example
    matchFn func(in T) bool
}

func (n *matcher[T]) Matches(in any) bool {
    val, ok := in.(T)
    if !ok {
        return false
    }
    return n.matchFn(val)
}

func (n *matcher[T]) String() string {
    return "some msg"
}
```

```golang
type matcherPerType[T any] struct {
    // implements any required fields.
    match T
}

func (n *matcherPerType[T]) Matches(in any) bool {
    val, ok := in.(T)
    if !ok {
        return false
    }
    // `reflect.DeepEqual` using only for example
    return reflect.DeepEqual(val, n.match)
}

func (n *matcherPerType[T]) String() string {
    return "some msg"
}
```

```golang
mockFoo.EXPECT().MyFunc(
    &matcher[string]{matchFn: func(in string) bool {
        return strings.EqualFold(in, "some_string")
    }},
    &matcherPerType[int]{match: 1},
).Return(true)
```

<kbd>[PLAYGROUND](https://go.dev/play/p/hEox8A7YhSo)</kbd>

Comment: thanks, but I'd want something more flexible that can match any type that is passed in.

Comment: More flexible, what does it mean !? You can write your custom behavior for matching  in `Matches`.

Comment: your example seems to work for string, but I want to pass in any other type. E.g., `matcher{myStruct}` or `matcher{myDifferentStruct}`. Do we implement one matcher per type?

Comment: I wrote the simplest example, you can implement `matcher` with any logic to access to the args...